# Java - Why no OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

I am trying to generate an OutOfMemoryError using the following code

```java
ArrayList container = new ArrayList();

while (true){
    Integer i = new Integer(1);
    container.add(i);
}
```

The application crashes but nothing is printed or dumped! Is this normal? should I pass some option to the java command? How could force the jvm to print out this message?

I am doing this because I have an application running on an embedded system (using cvm) that crashes with no trace. I am suspecting a memory leak, so I wanted to write a code that causes a memory leak to see what kind of message does the jvm output. This is why I wrote that code an when I ran it, it crashed but no trace was given, this is why I posted this question

Elie

Comment: Could you explain more why you're needing to do this? If it's to test this condition, there are better ways to go about it.

Comment: Does it even compile? I don't think Integer has no argument constructor.

Comment: @KirkWoll, maybe if they gave clear intentions a better answer could be given. Until then this is the best they will get from me.

Comment: No intentions required. The question is pretty clear.

Comment: "The application crashes but nothing is printed or dumped." No. The application doesn't even compile. You need to learn to distinguish compilation errors from run-time errors or exceptions, and all of those from crashes.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't explicit enough. I do put a number in the constructor of Integer it compiles, runs then crashes after several seconds. @Ash Burlaczenko, I edited my answer to give more details!

Comment: @EJP, ok, I forgot to put a number in the constructor, sorry for that!

Comment: I guess you should start another thread or change the question title. By the way, have you profiled your application to see the potential problems in it?

Answer (score 6):

I do get the

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

```
ArrayList container = new ArrayList();
while (true) {
    Integer i = new Integer(1);
    container.add(i);
}
```

if I put something in the Integer constructor. Otherwise, couldn't compile.

Comment: You can probably get there a lot faster by replacing `Integer i = new Integer(1)` with `int[] i = new int[10000]`...

Comment: Well, if an OOME is all you need, why not shoot straight for the top? `long[] x = new long[Integer.MAX_VALUE]`

Comment: Sorry if my question was incomplete, but of course I do put something in the constructor